Exposed BX Cable Concerns?
I was looking around outside of our house after we had some tree trimming done and noticed these electrical wires coming out of our home. Is this cause for concern? Should we be finding someone to come out and cover up the exposed wires that are visible outside of the metal covering?


It would be nice to know where/what that cable connects to inside of the house.  The answer is right, knowing where it is connected to might make the answer better.

That's a grounding rod. The wire that connects to it is a grounding conductor, which is typically bare wire, and is mostly there in case of a fault in your circuitry. The conduit added to it is additional protection that may be required for wire smaller than #6, but historically isn't present.
So no, it's not a concern unless the conductor itself is damaged or loose.

Thank you so much for the quick reply! I will make sure to keep an eye on it then for any future damage/looseness. Definitely eases my mind for when the next rain comes haha
